# Date Picker max date issue in lollipop devices

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I am working on a project where i have a datepicker. I am trying to set the max date and min date for it.The min date is 1 day after today and the max date is 11 days after today.**But the issue is in lollipop devices the last max day is shown as available but i am not able to select it**.**This issue is not there in lower android versions**.The following is what i have tried:

I call the datepicker method:

```
selectdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialogBox(999);
    }
});
```

I set the max date and min date as follows(Min day is one day after today, and the max date is 11 days after today):

```
public void showDialogBox(int x)
{
    Calendar cmin = Calendar.getInstance();
    cmin.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    int miny = cmin.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int minm = cmin.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int mind = cmin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String minDate=mind+"/"+minm+"/"+miny;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dateMin = null;
    try {
        dateMin = sdf.parse(minDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long minlong=dateMin.getTime();

    Calendar cmax = Calendar.getInstance();
    cmax.add(Calendar.DATE, 11);
    int maxy =cmax.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int maxm = cmax.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int maxd = cmax.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String maxDate=maxd+"/"+maxm+"/"+maxy;
    Date dateMax = null;
    try {
        dateMax = sdf.parse(maxDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long maxlong=dateMax.getTime();



    if (x== 999) {
        dpd=new DatePickerDialog(TheatreActivity.this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxlong);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minlong);
        dpd.show();
    }
}
```

The listener for the datepicker:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // arg1 = year
        // arg2 = month
        // arg3 = day
        showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
    }
};
```

The following code sets the date in the textview:

```
private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

    String dayy=day+"";
    String monthh=month+"";
    if(dayy.length()==1)
    {
        dayy="0"+dayy;
    }
    if(monthh.length()==1)
    {
        monthh="0"+monthh;
    }
    selectdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayy).append("-")
            .append(monthh).append("-").append(year));
    dateparam=year+"-"+monthh+"-"+dayy;
}
```

Please Help.
edit: 
issue is fixed by the following way

```
DatePickerDialog dpd=new DatePickerDialog(TheatreActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, myDateListener, year, month, day);
```

Comment: I've faced same problem, for me onDateSet method is not being called,please check it this for your case

Comment: @Nisarg .That is not my issue.On Date Set works.But i am not able to select the max date from the datepicker for lollipop devices.This issue is not there for older android versions like Kitkat.

Comment: are you develop with samsung device? if you are, there're some serious issues about material design implementation for pickers in samsung lollipop devices.

Comment: @savepopulation I have tested on Moto X Play (2015) and Yu Yureka device both with lollipop running on them.Both devices have this issue in them.

Comment: i'm also facing same issue. it is working in moto g with lollipop 5.0.2,but  in later versions, it is not working

Comment: hi @jojo any solution found?? even i am facing the same issue

Comment: @HardikAmal see edits

Answer (score 3):

**Try This One**

This will work on All devices **Lollipop** & **Marshmallow**

```
 mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
        mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 1));
```